# How do you use Radon programmatically

Tags: python

I'm trying to use radon located here: `https://radon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html`

I've done the following

```
from radon.raw import analyze
```

And in the documentation he has written:
radon.raw.analyze(source)

Where 'source' is the code.  I tried putting my file path into the code like so:

```
b = analyze(path_of_file)
```

But that return the result of that path_of_file contained 1 logical line of code which is wrong.

I also tried

```
b = radon.raw.analyze(path_of_file)
```

But that results in a red underline on my IED editor. I also tried:

```
import path_of_file
```

And then

```
b = analyze(path_of_file)
```

But that resulted in an attribute error.  He also has the following code which might help:

```
from radon.raw import analyze
>>> analyze("""def _split_tokens(tokens, token, value):
    '''Split a list of tokens on the specified token pair (token, value),
    where *token* is the token type (i.e. its code) and *value* its actual
    value in the code.
```

But I cannot figure out how to use this.  I'm just trying to get the raw function to output some data.  Once I get that figured out, I think I can get the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it expects code, but you're giving it a file path.  Have you tried something like this?

```
with open(path_of_file) as f:
    content = f.read()
    b = analyze(content)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I really appreciate that.